# syntax error in python both for instance information

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I am getting syntax error in:

```
'Starting: '.instance.id.' DNS{}:'.format(instance.dns.name)
```

while running the boto python API to show instance information

Comment: What have you done to research this problem? What is the _exact_ error that you get?

Comment: I can't say I'm unduly surprised - why did you think it might work?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the error you're getting is `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'instance'`, which is telling you precisely what the problem is:  `'Starting: '` is a string, and it has no attribute named `instance`.

Most likely the code needs to be something like this:

```
'Starting: ' + instance.id + ' DNS{}:'.format(instance.dns.name)
```

What that says is: "start with the string 'Starting: ', append to that the instance id, and then add The string "DNS" and append to that the value of "name" attribute of the instance id.

I don't know if that's 100% correct because I don't know what the attributes of `instance` are, nor do I know if it has an `id` attribute, and whether that `id` attribute has a `name` attribute.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: because that appears to be what the OP is attempting to do. It's bad, but I was trying to make the smallest changes possible to the OP's code.